# Where can I find a list of all OrientDB SQL projections?

Tags: sql, orientdb

I'm looking for documentation about projects in OrientDB SQL syntax. I've seen various examples, but I'd like a comprehensive list.

Examples of projections:

```
SELECT out('my_edge') FROM Person

SELECT expand(in('my_edge')) FROM Person

SELECT max('my_field') FROM Person

SELECT count(*) FROM Person
```

There are obviously lots of other ones out there, but I'd love it if there were some complete syntax documentation for this somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lots of different methods for the projections but this is list of the different functions that you can use (with examples) included your posted above:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html

While, here, you can find a couple of examples of queries:

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Query-Examples.html

Hope it helps

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, and the "Function Reference" is perfect for implementing the library I'm writing.